# ILogger.LogLevel is not enabled in C# unit tests

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, ilogger

I have an extension method for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger which checks if the given log level is enabled or not. And then proceeds with the actual logging.
When I try to unit test this method, I see that logger.IsEnabled(logLevel) always returns false for all the log levels in the unit test project, causing my tests to fail.

If I remove this isEnabled check, then my unit test passes.

Even though, a default log level is set in the appsettings.json file in the actual project as well as unit test project.

The code for my extension method is:

```
    public static class LoggerExtensions
    {
       public static void LogErrorExt(this ILogger logger, string? message, params object?[] args)
       {
         if (logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Error))
         {
           logger.LogError(message, args);
         }
       }
    }
```

The code for my unit test class is this:

```
[TestClass]
public class ImprovedExtensionsTests
{
  private readonly Mock < ILogger > _logger;
  
  public ImprovedExtensionsTests()
  {
    _logger = new Mock < ILogger > ();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestOne()
  {
    _logger.Object.LogErrorExt("Testing ", 12);
    
    _logger.Verify(x => x.Log(
      LogLevel.Error,
      It.IsAny < EventId > (),
      It.IsAny < It.IsAnyType > (),
      It.IsAny < Exception > (),
      (Func < It.IsAnyType, Exception, string > ) It.IsAny < object > ()), Times.Once);
  }
}
```

How can I set the log levels in unit test project and make them enabled while running the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the necessary setup for your ILogger mock, e.g.:

```
_logger.Setup(m => m.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Error)).Returns(true);
```

before the call to `LogErrorExt` (e.g. directly after `_logger = new Mock<ILogger>();`).

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. IsEnabled is still false. 
Can you please explain what you mean by "and similar for the Log method"?

Comment: You have to add the setup before calling `LogErrorExt`; did you do this? "and similar for the Log method": this is in fact not necessary; I will remove the sentence.

Comment: Thank you, this works! 
I added the setup before calling the method.